# Find the matrix associated to a given quadratic form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

Please help me complete my answer and find the matrix associated to a given quadratic form, here is my work and effort on that

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not the proper way to ask an answer and probably it will be downvoted and/or closed, please reformulate according to [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Notably you should also take a look to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I've edited the answer to give an example how you can improve that a little bit also you should learn to use MathJax.

Comment: Please try to rewrite down your work by MathJax, it can be an useful tools also in your career. Note that editing my answer you can copy and paste what I wrote and start from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for the 2-by-2 case

$$v^TAv=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=a^2+b^2$$